# Unwanted GRUB on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, startup, grub

While installing Linux Mint 19 to a USB, I managed to get GRUB installed on my Mac hard drive. I can still boot to the macOS if I hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key down.

How can I remove GRUB and revert my Mac hard drive back to booting with macOS?

I am fully backed up and if necessary can reformat and restore.

Comment: Please, edit you question and include the output from the command `diskutil list`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you did not create any new partitions on your Mac, then Grub will only exist in the hidden EFI partition. If there is no evidence of Grub in the Startup Manager menu, then you can just leave the Grub files on the EFI partition.

You can make macOS the default by holding down the <kbd>control</kbd> key before selecting macOS in the Startup Manager menu.

If Grub does appear in the Startup Manager, then you can fix this by removing the `EFI/BOOT` folder from the hidden EFI volume. To make this volume visible in the Finder, execute the following command.

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see your question about Diskutil list. I followed the directions in the longer answer, I found a BOOT and a ubuntu directory. I deleted both and the problem appears to be solved. Startup Manager only shows the Mac drive.

Comment: @Fading Light: The command `diskutil list` does not change your Mac. I just wanted to check if you allocated any space for Mint on your internal drive. Most likely you did not, so you can ignore my comment.

Comment: @Fading Light: Deleting the ubuntu directory was the correct thing to do. Although, leaving the ubuntu directory would not have hurt anything.

Comment: Alls well that ends well, Thanks again, big help, no lie.